# Format Angular Date for DB storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Thank you in advance

#### Q.1

I would like to format the [Angular-UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) date and time pickers. Every time I change the time or date the output is in the following manner `Today is: "2015-03-19T22:00:00.000Z"`. Obviously this is in correct. And my [Node-Mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) is filled with this date formatting

What's more bizzar is that There is 1 day subtracted in the date, On the time it subtracts 2 hours. My Time zone is GMT+2 See [MyBin](http://jsbin.com/repihohuxi/1/edit).

When I click on the date again to change it I want the date to stay as `2015-03-20` and the time to `11:20`

#### Q.2

How can I properly validate the following

```
<form name="BookingForm" ng-repeat="adult in myAdults">
 <h4>Adults</h4>
 <p>
    <input  required
    ng-required="true"
    name="adultName"
    ng-model="adultItem.name"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    ng-minlength = 3
    placeholder="Name">
<div class="error" ng-show="BookingForm.adultName.$dirty && BookingForm.adultName.$invalid">
    <small class="error btn-danger"
        ng-show="BookingForm.adultName.$error.required">
                Your name is required.
    </small>
    <small class="error btn-danger"
          ng-show="BookingForm.adultName.$error.minlength">
         Your name is required to be at least 3 characters
     </small>
 </div>
 </p>
</form>
```

My js Looks like this

```
$scope.adults = 4;
$scope.children = 2;
$scope.myAdults = [];

for (i = 0; i < $scope.adults; i ++) {
  $scope.myAdults.push({});
}
```

If I have just one form it works fine. But if I have more than one The validation messages only show up on the last one.

#### Most Important is Q1

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

datepicker is using angularjs `date` filter and it's localised but returned values are in GMT so `2015-03-19T22:00:00.000Z` is correct for `2015-03-12T00:00:00.000Z` as it will subtract 2 hours from midnight back which changes date as well, if you need a specific format you can do it with date filter as per plunker so

`{{'2015-03-19T22:00:00.000Z' | date:'dd-MMMM-yyyy'}}` in your timezone shall return `20-March-2015`

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

http://plnkr.co/edit/CoIS2BFK5O5EAaTu4Vc2?p=preview

#### javascript

```
$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```